# What's the name for a composable Polytope?

Tags: geometry

I would like to express the fact that a generic [Polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) can be generated from other basic geometric shapes, for example this shape

[image]

$C$ in this case is formed by a triangle + a quadrilateral, the catch that I want to communicate is that in this case my basic shape is a

- Polytope, *generally* of the same order of the space which contains it, in this case it's a 2D space and my shapes are 2D, but it's not mandatory, I can still get basic 2D shapes in 3D for example; Of course the space which I'm in works as a limit, I can't have 4D shapes in a 3D world for example .
- two different shapes, can be considered the same basic shape, as long as all the bottom level Polytopes ( up until the last level with 0 dimensions, a vertex ) that compose my top level Polytope are available with the same cardinality

Which means that a triangle and a quadrilateral are different because they are 2D Polytope with a different number of 1D and 0D Polytopes, the triangle has 3 vertices and 3 edges where a quadrilateral has 4 vertices and 4 edges.

Now take this rationale that I use to identify my basic shapes in a given dimension and try to find out a generic name that can describe the fact that $C$ is composable from $A+B$ in any dimension .

I'm unable to communicate this concept of "composable Polytopes from basic but different ( according to my rationale ) Polytopes" .

Answer (score 1):

Any polytope can be composed from "basic geometric shapes," i.e. simplices, so that condition doesn't add anything.
If you want them to be composed in a particular restricted manner, by starting with a simplex, then gluing another simplex along exactly one facet to a facet already there, and continuing in this manner, then it is called a "stacked polytope."

If you want to emphasize that you are considering only the combinatorial aspects (not differentiating between triangles of different shapes, for example) you can say "combinatorial polytope" or "isomorphism class of convex polytopes."

Maybe you are asking for your polytope to be composed from exactly two combinatorially different polytopes of the same dimension.
If the polytope is $d$-dimensional, you would say "The $d$-polytope $P$ is the union of two internally disjoint, combinatorially distinct $d$-polytopes $A$ and $B$."
But I think this is still trivial: you can slice any polytope by an arbitrary hyperplane and almost certainly get two combinatorially distinct polytopes.
Maybe you want all the faces of $A$ and $B$, of dimension 0 up to $d - 2$, to also be faces of $P$; this would be more restrictive. (For instance, in your example, all the vertices of $A$ and $B$ are also vertices of $C$. Not all the edges of $A$ or $B$ are edges of $C$, however.)

I don't think there's any such way to decompose an [antiprism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism), for example, so this is a real restriction.

By the way, your criterion for identifying combinatorially identical polytopes, that they have the same number of faces of each dimension, is much too broad. For instance, the [pentagonal pyramid and the tetragonal antiwedge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexahedron) both have 6 faces, 10 edges, and 6 vertices, but they aren't the same at all. "Combinatorially identical" or "isomorphic" conveys what you (almost certainly) mean, that the way the various faces are contained in each other are the same.